# Access API Gateway from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I have 1 Lambda Function connected to AWS Oracle RDS. I have exposed lambda to outer world via API Gateway.

How can i access same API Gateway in my EC2 Instance where i have my back-end services running?

```
[ec2-user@ip-22-22-22-22 dummy]$ ./telnet  10apexecute2.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com 443
Trying 55.11.144.98...
```

Please help

Comment: Can you clarify? Is the EC2 instance in a private subnet? Does it have internet access?

Comment: Is your instance public or private? If is public does it have an internet gateway attached to its routing table? If its private does it have a NAT attached to its routing table?

Comment: It's in private subnet. And do not have internet access.

Comment: Is a NAT attached to its route table @ANUJAGARWAL?

Comment: it's i restricted account i can not connect to internet. Is there any alternative way to access api gateway from within EC2

Comment: You can add a private endpoint to your VPC and your routing tables. Take a look at https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/

Comment: @ChrisWilliams thanks a lot it was i quick setup :)

Comment: No problem @ANUJAGARWAL, added answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As the account must be restrictive with its outbound communication over internet, the suggested solution would to make use of a VPC endpoint for API Gateway.

Once you create this endpoint, make sure to enable the "Enable Private DNS Name" option to override the DNS resolution for `execute-api` endpoints to speak to resolve through your VPC endpoint.

More information can be found in this blog post: [Introducing Amazon API Gateway Private Endpoints | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/)